# Accessing JSON Object

Tags: json

If i have a JSON Object

var Obj = { col1 : 'data' };

the value 'col1' and 'data' are dynamically created.

Here i can access 'data' as Obj.col1. But want to read the value 'col1'.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
for (var name in Obj) {
    alert(name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column name is available from the JavaScript:

```
var columnName = "col1";
alert(Obj[columnName]); // alerts "data"
```

If 'col1' isn't present in the object, it fails gracefully returning `null` without raising an exception.

You may need to pass the the dynamic column name from serverside to clientside though. Something like:

```
var columnName = "<% columnName %>";
```